# Sorting array by comma separated date

Tags: php, mysql

I want to ORDER BY (ASC) DATE column but in that field there are multiple value separate by comma

> 04/10/2017,04/10/2017,04/11/2017,04/12/2017,04/13/2017,04/14/2017,04/17/2017

[Please see table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS4t2.png)

[image]

I m not sure it is possible by mysql or we sorting in array

Comment: Perfect example of why you should *always* normalize your schema.

Comment: You shouldn't put comma-separated lists in database columns, you should use a relation table.

Comment: Which date in the list do you want to sort by?

Comment: @barmar upcoming date should show first

Comment: You can't do this untill you iterate each row and use method like `explode` and then compare. Otherwise apply what @GurV said

Comment: @Mayurm show how should look TOP 10 records after sorting

Comment: Case study in poor DB design. As @Niklesh said, you're going to need to iterate those records first. Get a unique set of dates as an array, then as a subarray for each date add the event ID that exists for it.